How to measure and control the current of a high-side switch
I'm trying to build a high-side switch circuit with actively adjustable current limit, since I couldn't able to find a suitable current limiting high-side switch controller for that purpose.
My idea is to use a power(current) monitor IC like INA232 and then connect the shunt resistor on the drain side of the NMOS, which the NMOS is driven by a high-side switch controller IC.
shunt resistor determines the max allowable current on the switch, Let's say, 30A. On an application, I would like to set a temporary limit of the switch to, 20A. The only way to reduce current output is by PWMing the NMOS when INA232 alarms me the load has pulling more than 20A current, But how can I know what duty cycle can output exactly 20A without knowing the load? (The load will be externally connected) I'm thinking about polling INA232's current reading while adjusting duty cycle until the target reading has been met. But if there are many switches on the board that might take too many MCU resources for that purpose only?  Is there a more effective and simpler solution for this?

"But how can I know what duty cycle can output exactly 20A without knowing the load?" You probably cant, but would hysteresis or PID controller be enough for you? How precisely do you need your 20 A setpoint? It sounds a bit like an XY problem. What is the load and why do you need to limit it to 20 A?

Please clarify what you mean by "without knowing the load". Knowing its dynamics is needed to implement a closed loop control.

@winny resistive load like LEDs. Limiting it's current = dimming the light, the precision wouldn't be high, a few hundred mA off is fine.

@devnull it's more like a controller that controls external resistive loads like LEDs. So closed loop control is not possible.

Thanks for the clarification. "I'm thinking about polling INA232's current reading while adjusting duty cycle until the target reading has been met" should be consistent with "closed loop control is not possible". As @winny mentioned, it is sounding like an XY problem.

LEDs are not resistive load. Why don't you use/build a 20 A constant current regulator?

@winny might be more complicated than high-side switch?

@devnull Yeah.... if my proposal solution is not good enough to solve this then I'm open to other opinions.  Or the main goal is : to build a high-side switch with active current limit adjusting

I doubt it. There are plenty of off-the shelf solutions for building a constant current regulator. Would a 20 A CC limit solve your problems?

@winny this CCR circuit should be adjustable 2A to 30A max. Then that would solve the problem.

If that's what you need, then I would recommend you make an adjustable 2-30 A high side constant current regulator.

@winny tried that but I was having a hard time finding the suitable ic for that purpose. I mean, for low voltage (5V and such), low current applications I've seem people using Battery Charging IC to be CCR, but for 12-24V 2-30A? not quite..

I didn't find one fully integrated for you, but especially for a controller, you should be able to have a output current inner loop and a regular voltage as outer loop. With constant current, you can also cheat and use several in parallel if you don't find one which can do 30 A for you. I suspect you will end up with either a two-phase controller or just two 15 A capable bucks in parallel.

I can't answer your question, because what you are asking for is impractical. I can show you why though.
Let's say you have a 24V power supply, and a load that develops 20V when passing 30A. All linear current limiting solutions will have a similar form, containing some element whose role is to dispense with excess voltage while passing the requisite current:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left I use a simple resistor, R1, the value of which would be chosen depending on the load. In this example R1 chosen to develop 4V when passing 30A. It works, but only if the load is known to develop the remaining 20V at 30A.
That isn't what you want. You require current to be limited to 30A maximum regardless of load, which is achieved on the right with a very typical linear current regulator. This design varies its effective resistance between A and B, to whatever value is necessary to pass exactly 30A. It's really just a "smart" R1.
Note: a real life limiter would probably have two or more MOSFETs, but that's not relevant to the point I'm trying to make.
In both instances, the boxed current limiting element is passing 30A, and has 4V across it. Therefore, power dissipated in that element, which is the product of voltage across and current through it, is:
$$ P = I \times V = 30A \times 4V = 120W $$
This is what R1 or those MOSFETs would have to dissipate, at or near 100% PWM duty cycle. That would require enormous heat-sinks, with fans, and proper air ducting.
A fixed voltage source is clearly problematic here, because there will always be some "excess voltage" to dispense with. What you need is a power supply that adjusts its output voltage to exactly the right value necessary to pass the requested current, regardless of the load. Such a thing is called a "constant current supply".
For such large currents, you really need a switching constant-current supply, which would be much more efficient. It will also need to have some input that permits you to tell it how much current to produce. I do not feel confident to design one off-the-cuff, and present it here, nor am I confident in the ability of an average reader to build it well enough for it to not explode or catch fire. That's why we usually rely on companies like TDK-Lambda and Meanwell to spend thousands of hours and dollars designing them, and even more thousands of hours testing them, before they arrive on the shelves for us to buy.

Then check out this product here: https://www.bajadesigns.com/products/spod-bantamx-hd-universal/?sku=BXHDUNI36 "Current-sensing MOSFETs controlled by a microprocessor (no fuses & relays)" "Programmable Current Limiting" if there will be that much of power dissipation, then this product should be loaded with fans and heatsink rather just a compact metal box?

@TravisSu This product cuts off power when an over-current condition is detected. That's very different from limiting current. Did you just downvote me?

I did not realize it cuts off power rather than just limiting current. That just makes sense now.  And I did not downvote you.

@TravisSu Besides, that probably contains switching regulators, which as I explained behave very differently from linear ones, and are much more efficient, not requiring so much heat management. This is a commercial product with a lot of research, development and testing behind it, which explains the price. Not something I could really compete with in an answer here.

I honestly think that product only uses external Nmos high-side switch controller with current sensing IC that when current exceeds the limit the mcu can turn of the switch hence "cuts off power". The output is not regulated but just routes the input power though a "switch" and then outputs it.


The only way to reduce current output is by PWMing the NMOS

That only works for inductive loads, and you'd need a freewheeling diode as well.
For resistive loads, PWM-ing doesn't reduce the current. It turns the too-high of a current on and off.

But how can I know what duty cycle can output exactly 20A without knowing the load?

You assume that this idea will work. It can't. Some loads will behave badly or get destroyed from such attempts at PWM-ing.
You're perhaps awkwardly trying to make a circuit breaker - so make one. Once it trips, it should turn off until it's manually reset - or at least after some time, nothing "fast" like PWM!

"You're perhaps awkwardly trying to make a circuit breaker" It looks like this. In a comment with a link to a commercial product some descriptions like "Protection against: overheating, over-current, shorts..." go in that direction (not current control).
